# Why do I need to make a call to clear before calling glReadPixels?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I am currently trying to read back texture data to store that data in physical storage.

The following code handles the read and then transfer the resultant float buffer to a worker thread for compression and final storage.

```
    //Create file for storing data
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Store required map data to recreate current map data
int currentFramebuffer = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &currentFramebuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _terrainFrameBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, _globalTerrainRenderMap, 0);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

//Check for valid framebuffer
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 0, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFramebuffer);
    return false;
}

float *mapBuffer = new float[_terrainMapSize*_terrainMapSize * 4];
if (mapBuffer != nullptr)
{
    glReadPixels(0, 0, _terrainMapSize, _terrainMapSize, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, (void *)mapBuffer);

    //Set OpenGL fence object
    GLsync gSync;
    gSync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);

    //wait for OpenGL fence to process data
    if (gSync)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            GLenum waitReturn = glClientWaitSync(gSync, GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, 1);
            if (waitReturn == GL_ALREADY_SIGNALED || waitReturn == GL_CONDITION_SATISFIED)
                break;
        }
        glDeleteSync(gSync);
    }

    //Spawn compress and save thread to store file
    std::thread t=std::thread(CompressAndSaveMapFile, mapBuffer, _terrainMapSize, _terrainMapSize, mapFilename);
    t.detach();
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFramebuffer);
```

At the very beginning of this code, you will see a call to glClearColor followed by a call to glClear(). If these lines are omitted then glReadPixels returns seemingly garbage data. But with these two lines, it returns the correct texture data.

Now my question is this, why would I need to clear the system framebuffer before I setup the read framebuffer and call glReadPixels()? Any ideas?

The system works flawlessly with these two lines, just more than a little curious as to why this seemingly redundant calls need to be there.

Comment: FYI: There's no point in using a sync object after a read directly into main memory. Once `glReadPixels` returns, you will have the pixel data. Avoiding that is why PBOs exist, but you're not using one.

Comment: PBO use actually slowed the code down. Considerably actually.

Comment: Switched over to using glGetTexImage and the code works without caveats and is much simpler to read. Although performance of glGetTexImage is phenomenally slower than a framebuffer read for some reason.